# What is WebCrypto.subtle.decrypt analog for node.js crypto.createDecipheriv (AES-CTR algorithm)?

Tags: node.js, nginx, cryptography, webcrypto, njs

I am trying to rewrite old NodeJs encryption algorithm [from](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptocreatedecipherivalgorithm-key-iv-options)

```
crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv[, options])
```

[into](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#subtledecryptalgorithm-key-data) webcrypto

```
subtle.decrypt(algorithm, key, data)
```

This code work good enough with AES-128-CTR algorithm

```
const algorithm = 'aes-128-ctr';

const iv = '0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
const privateKey = '16Random_Letters';
const hexBufferFromIv = Buffer.from(iv, 'hex');
const utfBufferFromPrivateKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'utf8');

function oldEncryptData(data: string): string {
  const cipher = createCipheriv(
    algorithm,
    utfBufferFromPrivateKey,
    hexBufferFromIv,
  );
  let crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');
  crypted += cipher.final('base64');
  return crypted;
}

function oldDecryptData(data: string): string {
  const decipher = createDecipheriv(
    algorithm,
    utfBufferFromPrivateKey,
    hexBufferFromIv,
  );
  let dec = decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8');
  dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}

async function testDecrypt() {
  const sourceText = `any text to encrypt!`;

  const encryptedText = oldEncryptData(sourceText);

  const decryptedText = oldDecryptData(encryptedText);

  return sourceText === decryptedText;
}

testDecrypt().then(console.log);
```

Right now I test this code and WebCrypto examples in nodejs, but as a final result I wont to move webCrypto.subtle.decrypt functionality into NGINX njs and as I know, njs doesn't support other options for decryption except for WebCrypto.

Interface for WebCrypto decrypt for AES-CTR in general looks like

```
const data = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
  {
    name: "AES-CTR",
    counter,     // BufferSource
    length: 128, // 1-128
  },
  key,  // AES key
  encData, // BufferSource
);
```

And I don't undersatnd.

1. counter is the same thing as the `Initialization vector` in `createDecipheriv` method?
2. How I should generate key for `subtle.decrypt` method from the same passphrase?
3. Do I need to do any additional transformation from or to `base64` or `utf8` encoding to reproduce input and output encoding in `cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');` and in `decipher.update(data, 'base64', 'utf8');` methods?

Comment: Most of your questions are answered in the documentation or can be derived from it: `counter` corresponds to the IV. `decrypt()` expects a `CryptoKey` (i.e. the key has to be imported). Conversions may be necessary if the data is not in supported formats (e.g. a Base64 encoded ciphertext would have to be converted to an `ArrayBuffer` etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Topaco for hints. I'll write a more complete answer. Maybe it will be useful for someone.

1. Yes, `Initialization vector` and `counter` can be treated as the same thing.
2. For generating a key from the same passphrase you should use [importKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/importKey) method. And you should sent the same ArrayBuffer from the passphrase as in `createCipheriv` method.
3. Yes, if your old method used some specific encoding and decoding, you should repeat the same encoding/decoding logic after Webcrypto.SubtleCrypto.encrypt() and decrypt() methods.

Full workable example may looks something like

```
import { webcrypto } from 'crypto';

const iv = '0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF';
const privateKey = '16Random_Letters';
const hexBufferFromIv = Buffer.from(iv, 'hex');
const utfBufferFromPrivateKey = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'utf8');

async function generateKeyFromPassPhrase(): Promise<CryptoKey> {
  return webcrypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    utfBufferFromPrivateKey,
    {
      name: 'AES-CTR',
    },
    true,
    ['decrypt', 'encrypt'],
  );
}

async function newEncryptData(data: string): Promise<string> {
  const key = await generateKeyFromPassPhrase();

  const encryptResult = await webcrypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: 'AES-CTR',
      length: 128,
      counter: hexBufferFromIv,
    },
    key,
    Buffer.from(data),
  );

  return Buffer.from(encryptResult).toString('base64');
}

async function newDecryptData(data: string): Promise<string> {
  const key = await generateKeyFromPassPhrase();

  const decryptResult = await webcrypto.subtle.decrypt(
    {
      name: 'AES-CTR',
      length: 128,
      counter: hexBufferFromIv,
    },
    key,
    Buffer.from(data, 'base64'),
  );

  return Buffer.from(decryptResult).toString();
}

async function testDecrypt() {
  const sourceText = `any text to encrypt!`;
  const encrypted2 = await newEncryptData(sourceText);

  const decrypted2 = await newDecryptData(encrypted2);

  return sourceText === decrypted2;
}

testDecrypt().then(console.log);
```